# How can you vary the facts using lists in clipspy

Tags: python, clips, clipspy

I have tried to vary the facts using lists and a cycle for but I have not succeeded, The way I tried it is to create a list for each variable in the template and then apply an cycle for but it didn't work.
The example python code in which I have tried it is:

```
import clips

DEFTEMPLATE_DORMITORIO = """
(deftemplate Dormitorio
    (slot Presencia (type SYMBOL))
    (slot Iluminación (type SYMBOL)))
"""

DEFTEMPLATE_SALADEESTAR = """
(deftemplate SalaDeEstar
    (slot Presencia (type SYMBOL))
    (slot Iluminación (type SYMBOL)))
"""

DEFTEMPLATE_GENERALES = """
(deftemplate Generales
    (slot Hora (type INTEGER)))
"""

env = clips.Environment()
env.build(DEFTEMPLATE_DORMITORIO)
env.build(DEFTEMPLATE_SALADEESTAR)
env.build(DEFTEMPLATE_GENERALES)
env.load('reglas2.CLP')

Dormitorio = env.find_template('Dormitorio')
fact_Dormitorio = Dormitorio.assert_fact(Presencia = clips.Symbol('Si'),
                                         Iluminación = clips.Symbol('OFF'))

SalaDeEstar = env.find_template('SalaDeEstar')
fact_SalaDeEstar = SalaDeEstar.assert_fact(Presencia = clips.Symbol('Si'),
                                           Iluminación = clips.Symbol('OFF'))

Generales = env.find_template('Generales')
fact_Generales = Generales.assert_fact(Hora = 2100)

env.run()            
for facts in env.facts():
    
    print(facts)
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want to change and how? You can modify the facts slot as documented in here: https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#template-facts

Comment: what I mean is that, if it is possible, for example, in the case of the variable "presencia" instead of just defining 'Si' to put a list of the form ['Si', 'No'] and run through it with a cycle for

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a `multislot` for that.

```
import clips

DEFTEMPLATE_DORMITORIO = """
(deftemplate Dormitorio
  (multislot Presencia (type SYMBOL))
  (slot Iluminacion (type SYMBOL)))
"""

environment = clips.Environment()
environment.build(DEFTEMPLATE_DORMITORIO)

template = environment.find_template("Dormitorio")
fact = template.assert_fact(Presencia=[clips.Symbol('Si'),
                                       clips.Symbol('No')],
                            Iluminacion=clips.Symbol('OFF'))

for element in fact['Presencia']:
    print(element)
```

Comment: If I have all the variables with multislot is there any way to go evaluating one by one the facts of the lists, for example, apply the rules to the first slot of the facts and then to the second and so on.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to ask. I would recommend give a read to CLIPS [Basic Programming Guide](https://clipsrules.sourceforge.io/documentation/v640/bpg.pdf) to better understand the capabilities of the platform so you can better formulate the questions.

A `multislot` is a CLIPS `multifield` type. You can operate over it via the `$` operator and store it in variables using `$?`. For example `$?presencia`. You can then check in the variable the contents you are looking for.